# AppMetrics/Grafana - problem with determining metrics type

Tags: grafana, influxdb, metrics

Let's assume there is flow which can change a status of a transaction to one of the following: `Started`, `InProc1`, `InProc2`,`Succeeded`, `Failed`. Every transaction can transition through different stages, e.g. `Started -> InProc1 -> Failed`.

Now, I'd like to build a dashboard showing the amount of transactions in a given status for a particular time interval, e.g. `interval_1: [Started:20, Failed:15, InProc1:5]`.

I'm having troubles identifying the correct metric type to use with AppMetrics/Grafana so I could do that. `Meters` would mark every transition (so for my examples I'd have three events for every new status change like `_-> Started`, `Started -> InProc1`, etc.). Thus, if I want to group per transaction status tag, this won't work because I'd have three entries in my source (I just want the last one, the actual state). Similar problem would be with `Counters` (only incrementing the value) and for `Gauges` there is no option to pass a string value (which probably doesn't make sense anyway).

So, ideally, I'd like to have a possibility to replace a value to a new one when the transition happens (not just increment the counter), so I could display it per given timestamp. I feel like I'm missing something :)

**EDIT:**
Please take a look at the below example data:

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Value</th>
    <th>State</th>
    <th>Id</th>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Started</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>InProc1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>InProc2</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Finished</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Started</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>InProc1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Failed</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And the query:
`SELECT last("value"), count("value") FROM "source" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval), "state", "id" fill(null)`

Comment: I would say you need to define first what is "AppMetrics" and how it is related to InfluxDB which you used as a question tag.

Comment: AppMetrics is a framework I use to push my metrics into the source which in this case is InfluxDb. This frameworks allow me to push all metric types like histograms, meters, gauges, etc. Sorry, maybe I tagged this wrong, it's more about the correct approach to Grafana in terms of presenting the data the way I described.

Answer (score 0):

From the InfluxDB perspective (you need to "translate" it to the "AppMetrics" framework perspective):
`state` will be a tag with values `Started, InProc1, InProc2,Succeeded, Failed`, you need also `transactionid` tag (otherwise you may have a problem with deduplication) + you need field, so generate some (e.g. `value` and save always value 1)

Query: generally, use LAST() selector to select last values and then COUNT aggregation function with GROUP BY `state` tag (and/or time)

Problem: InfluxDB is not designated for updates, so if you really need "possibility to replace", then InfluxDB is not a good choice (InfluxDB solution will be very hackish). Relational database will be a better option.

Comment: I don't quite understand how this would work (please see my edit to the question to see example data and query based on your answer).
1. Why would I need the LAST() selector if the value doesn't matter? Why can't I just go with count("value") right away?
2. I still need to GROUP BY `state` and `id` because of the deduplication you mentioned. 3. This still won't behave as a replacement, as for state `InProc1` it would show `count:2` which is not true, as the final state of transaction with `id:1` is `Finished` and for `id:2` is `Failed`, so there should be no entries for `InProc1`.

Comment: I was trying to make a query as you suggested, but it doesn't seem to be working: `SELECT count("last") FROM (SELECT last("value") FROM "db.source" WHERE  $timeFilter GROUP BY "transaction_id") GROUP BY "status", time($__interval)`. Can you tell me what's wrong with that?